# Add existing item to solution at runtime in wpf

Tags: wpf

I am creating resource file at runtime in `WPF`.

It is being created and displayed in resource folder, but it is not showing in solution, even after refreshing the folder.

When i do it manually (`add exsiting item`), then it is being added.

How to add it to solution whenever it is being created?

My code is:

```
public void LaguageCulture(string languageid)
{
    try
    {
        SqlParameter[] param = new SqlParameter[1];
        param[0] = new SqlParameter("@lagid", languageid);
        //languageid =3 
        var dsResources = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(_objSqlConnection, "sproc_GetResourceNames", param);
        string culturecode = string.Empty;
        if (dsResources.Tables[1].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            culturecode = dsResources.Tables[1].Rows[0][0].ToString();
        }
        FileInfo file = new FileInfo(System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath.Replace("\\bin\\Debug", "") + "\\Resources\\EnglishResource." + culturecode + ".resx"); // Culture code is en-US 
        if (!file.Exists)
        {
            var resx = new ResXResourceWriter(System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath.Replace("\\bin\\Debug", "") + "\\Resources\\EnglishResource." + culturecode + ".resx");
            if (dsResources.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < dsResources.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    resx.AddResource(dsResources.Tables[0].Rows["ResourceName"].ToString(), dsResources.Tables[0].Rows["ResourceValue"].ToString());
                }
            }
            resx.Generate();
            //Application.Current.Resources.Add(culturecode + ".resx", resx); 
            resx.Close();
        }
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(culturecode);
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(culturecode);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure to understand the question, but I guess you will have to manipulate `csproj` or `sln` files to reach your goal.

Answer (score 0):

You have to programmatically add some lines in your `.csproj` (which is a xml file).

Maybe something like :

```
<EmbeddedResource Include="Resources\EnglishResource.en-US.resx">
  <Generator>PublicResXFileCodeGenerator</Generator>
</EmbeddedResource>
```